# ASP.NET core web api middleware overriding cors

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi

When I comment out the connection to the middleware in program.cs, everything works fine except, I need to use api keys. When uncomment it back in, and pass a valid api key in the headers, I get this error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url redacted]. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 401.

My `program.cs` is

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7029");
                      });
});

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My middleware is:

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private const string APIKEY = "XApiKey";

    public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEY, out var extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Api Key was not provided ");
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEY);

        if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized client");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

When I call the API from Postman without the api key in the headers, it returns

> Api Key was not provided

and with an incorrect api key in the headers, it returns

> Unauthorized client

With a correct api key in the headers, it returns whatever it does.

Any help is appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you should put `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` before `app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();`. The execution of middleware is sequential.

```
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

For more details, you can check [the middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order-1).

[image]